# Flextable: change cell value if it meets a condition and formatting

Tags: r, formatting, cell, edit, flextable

I have a dataset (called example) like the following one.

```
mic <- rep(c("One", "Two", "Tree", "Four"), each = 3)  
pap <- rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), each = 3)  
ref <- rep(c("Trial 1", "Trial 2", "Trial 3", "Trial 4"), each = 3)  
prob <- c(rep(NA,4), "Nogood", NA, "Bad", "Nogood", "Norel", NA, "Bad", "Nogood")  
example <- data.frame(Micro = mic, Paper = pap, Reference = ref, Problem = prob)  
example
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsgaJ.jpg)

I would like to merge cells vertically when consecutive cells have identical
values so I use *flextable* **merge_v()** function.

```
ft_example <- example %>%
flextable() %>%
merge_v(j = ~ Micro + Paper + Reference + Problem) %>%
theme_vanilla()
ft_example
```

I obtain the following table when knitting in Word:
[Table obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KdHw.jpg)

Is there a way to:

1. Insert a posteriori the value "None identified" in the  empty
   cells in the "Problem" field that are merged together; and
2. Remove the inappropriate horizontal lines in the "Problem" field when
   there is one (or more) not empty cells and some empty cells so that
   there is one horizontal line clearly  separating each combination of
   Micro, Paper, Reference and horizontal lines  separating only non
   empty cells in the Problem field?

You can see the desired result here below:
[Table desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gTI8.jpg)